# Plot graph is not corrected when using multiple csv files using panda python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Here I have three csv file and I merged that three cv files together. According to the summation equation I tried to find Y values.

Then that y values plot with the time. When I plot the graph my first line and the last line of graph connected each other.

I don't know why is that coming. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

my code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv',"," )
df2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv',"," )
df3 = pd.read_csv('data3.csv',"," )


df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['date','time','x'])
df2 = df1.copy()
df3 = df1.copy()
data = df1.append([df2, df3])
```

After that equation:

my summation equation,

[image]

> n = time difference in between two rows

my code:

```
def y_convert(X,time):
   Y=0
  if x == 10:            
      for k in range(0,time):
         Y=np.sum(X*k)
    else:            
       for k in range(0,time):
       Y=np.sum(X*k)
return Y
```

Then convert time difference into minute and then apply this code to find y

```
data['time_diff'] = pd.to_datetime(data["time"])
data['delta'] = (data['time_diff']-data['time_diff'].shift()).fillna(0)
data['t'] = data['delta'].apply(lambda x: x  / np.timedelta64(1,'m')).astype('int64') % (24*60)

X = data['X'].astype(int)
time=data['t'].astype(int)

Y = data.apply(lambda x: y_convert(x.X,x.time), axis=1)
```

Then I tried to plot the graph

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],    format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(data['date'], data['Y'])
ax.set_xlabel
ax.set_ylabel
plt.show()
```

plot graph:
[image]

my csv file:(format of one csv file)

[image]

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Nope this question didn't have answer for my question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is with sorting.

Solution is [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'], 
                              format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)


data = data.sort_values('date')
```

Comment: It worked properly. Thank you very much. Can you little bit explain why do we use sort_value while merging three csv file?

Comment: @team - Because data - after append are not sorted, so get linked first and last value in graph.

Comment: Got it thank you for helping me.